# Always have 'nil' value for `NSDate` property

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, epoch, nstimeinterval

I'm retrieving an epoch time value from an API in iOS. I have a property on my class that I want to store that value in, `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDate *dateAndTime;`.

Below is the code I have to get the date / time value and convert it into a proper format. I can see from my logs that the epoch time value, `timestamp`, is being converted to a proper format:

```
    // get create datetime from timestamp
    NSString *timestamp = [details myString_stringForKey:@"create_date"];
    // Convert NSString to NSTimeInterval
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [timestamp doubleValue];
    NSDate *epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to %@", timestamp, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:epochNSDate]);
```

However, when I go to set the value of `self.dateAndTime`, I always return a `nil` value, and I have no idea why:

```
self.dateAndTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timestamp];
```

Can someone give me another set of eyes on this one?

Comment: What is the value of `timestamp`? Based on your code it seems like it's a numeric string which obviously wouldn't fit the format you are setting on your date formatter.

Comment: for property instead of copy can you use strong

Comment: Did you check the variables before `dateAndTime` ? ie `timestamp`, `seconds`, `epochNSDate`. All what you expect? Your date format string looks ok, but can try using `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` on `dateFormatter` instead of `setDateFormat` to verify that that's not what's causing the problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense anyway, you already created a date object from the timestamp and stored it in `epochNSDate`, just give that date to your property